# Does WordPress get_users support arrays?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know if the function `get_users` supports an array of user roles? My guess is that it doesn't.

I have the following which works:

```
$args =array(
   'role' => 'line_manager'
);
$blogusers = get_users($args);
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
```

I then adapt the above to look like the following and it returns empty.

```
$args =array(
    'role' => array('line_manager','administrator')
);
$blogusers = get_users($args);
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
```

If it doesn't support arrays, is there a workaround other than doing a `wp_query`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, [it doesn't support arrays](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L496).
That's a string to be used in the SQL query `LIKE '%\"line_manager\"%'`.

But a simple [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) can solve this:

```
$argsa =array( 'role' => 'administrator' );
$a = get_users( $argsa );

$argsb =array( 'role' => 'line_manager' );
$b = get_users( $argsb );

$users = array_merge( $a, $b );
```

You could also use the action hook [`pre_user_query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_user_query), but it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

As @brasofilo said you essentially need to build separate queries and combine the results. Here's an alternative and slightly shorter {example} way to do it -assuming you want to just collect ID's:

```
$custom_ids = implode(',',get_users('role=administrator&field=ID')); 
$custom_ids .= ",".implode(',',get_users('role=line_manager&field=ID'));
```